# Kill off the 1%... or the 5%?

Tags: economy, politics

What would happen to America if we were to kill off the top 1% wealthiest people and spread around their wealth to the remaining Americans? How much money would everyone get? I guess this is a way to understand just *how* much more the top has than the rest.

What if we did the same to the top 5%?

Would there be more of a [balance in politics](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/10/11/us/politics/2016-presidential-election-super-pac-donors.html)? Would there be (subjectively) as much suffering, or more, or less? Would there be less hatred/polarized views of things? Would we be able to stop homelessness, or stop people from starving? What if we devoted all the money to food-- since the top 1% certainly are not.

Comment: Spread the wealth throughout America? or throughout the world?

Comment: @newton1212 America

Comment: What would you like the answer to be?  Is it really going to just be a monetary transaction, or might people pay attention to how the executions were done?  My assumption would be that the way you went about these killings would have a great deal of influence as to the answers to your question.

Comment: I guess ideally I was wondering about this in a non-realistic way where the 1% vanished and their non-affluent loved ones/society didn't care or think about what happened; in other words, more of the economic implications than the moral issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you did this to the 1%, you would be killing 3,000,000 Americans. This is a disaster larger than 9/11. Much, much larger, and executed on purpose.

If you did this to the 5%, you would be killing 15,000,000 Americans. As a comparison, according to the [Jewish Virtual Library](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Holocaust/36qs.html), 6,000,000 Jews died in the Holocaust.

I'd be worried about what *lead to* this in America more than what would happen afterwards, honestly. The sheer number of people who would have to be executed - anyone making more than about $196,000 per year - is staggering. Killed for taking advantage of a system, killed for having rich parents.

Who would be next? The *new* 1% and 5%? As far as I'm aware, only Stalin's 20 million deaths would rival such an extinction perpetrated by the government on its own people.

Would there be subjectively as much suffering? To be clear, you're talking about a genocide.

The sudden lack of doctors (average income USD164,000), lawyers (average income USD130,000), politicians (average income for a Congressman, USD131,000), and the President (currently USD400,000) would cause more issues for everyone else.

---

Ignoring morality - and the fact that we would be getting rid of the higher-ups of Google, Microsoft, Facebook, etc., and probably ending the jobs of everyone who works for companies whose owners earn more than either USD500,000 or USD150,000 - it would lead to a quick boom followed by a bust.

America's net worth is ~USD87 trillion, and the 1% controls a third of that. However, there are still 295,000,000 Americans, minus whoever died if it provoked a war while exterminating a segment of its population.

If there are 295,000,000 surviving Americans, each one of them will receive approximately USD100,000. Minus income taxes, which are high for numbers like this. More like USD70,000.

The issue is that they would receive no training (and a college education will blow most of this, anyway), and there would be no incentive to receive a training. You know how most rags-to-riches stories end up with the main character losing it all after blowing everything very quickly? I imagine it would end much like that on an economy wide scale.

Especially if people were afraid of becoming a part of the 1% for fear of another genocide. This would make people afraid to start businesses, afraid to invest, afraid to buy anything that might become an investment, for fear of becoming a social class which apparently society has no qualms about killing en masse. And considering that the owners of large companies would be dead, the crashed stock market would cause some economic issues, too.

---

"Would there be more of a balance in politics? Would there be (subjectively) as much suffering, or more, or less? Would there be less hatred/polarized views of things? Would we be able to stop homelessness, or stop people from starving?"

A balance in politics after executing a genocide? Unlikely. Think Russia after World War II and Germany during it. This is a society that just executed 15,000,000 people for taking advantage of - or their family members taking advantage of, in the case of children - a currently capitalist system, and might do it again - thereby shooting itself in the foot by discouraging people from learning how to use their newfound wealth.

Less suffering during and after a genocide? You see, there's always going to be a top 1% in any group with more than 100 people, a top 5% in a group with more than 20 people, and an unstable government would just keep going down the rabbit hole.

Less hatred? This doesn't make any sense. I certainly think the Holocaust was a time of hatred, and this proposed "Final Solution" to wealth inequality would either kill half as many people as the Holocaust or more than twice as many - and even more if violence breaks out, which it probably would. Remember, many Republicans are staunchly against socialism - states like Texas would be irate. Outright rebellion looks likely.

As for food insecurity? Homelessness? In reality, if the US attempted to kill 1 in 20 Americans, there would probably be a civil unrest, maybe even civil war. Right now, in Syria, half of the population has been displaced, and many are now refugees. Sure, after killing the 5%, these people would be wealthy… but would they be safe from war?

Comment: "As far as I'm aware, only Stalin's 20 million deaths would rival such an extinction perpetrated by the government on its own people." Stalin was a piker. Mao's Great Leap Forward (1958 - 1962) may have produced 40-50 million deaths.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast *long whistle* It's depressing what humans are capable of doing to each other. (Although I should note that the high estimates for Stalin are around 62 million. Not that that makes it better.)

Comment: A 62 million number has to include WWII deaths, which were enormous. Wartime deaths of your own population are not usually seen as actions by the head of the government.

Answer (score 4):

If you gave everyone in the US \$70,000 then some would save it.  Others would immediately consume it.  Since this money is currently all savings, this means that there would be a drop in savings and investment.  The stock market would crash, as a substantial portion of the stocks are included in the liquidated wealth.  Note that eliminating the rich means that there's no longer anyone to buy that much stock.  But then it's no longer \$70,000 per person.

Let's look at the specific case of Donald Trump.  He's worth about \$3 or \$4 billion and has about 10% of that in cash-like investments (mostly things like stocks and bonds still).  The bulk of his wealth is in the form of real estate.  So you take all his real estate and sell it.  To whom?

You'd end up selling mansions for middle class prices because no one could pay mansion prices.  But then what happens to the market for normal houses?  Why pay \$500,000 for an expensive house when you could buy a mansion for that?  So the \$500,000 house becomes worth \$200,000 and the \$200,000 houses become worth \$100,000.  So someone with a \$200,000 mortgage is now \$100,000 underwater.  There goes that windfall.

The construction market bottoms out.  People are better off buying existing housing than new housing.  This causes a recession.  Perhaps they could go work in a factory instead -- there'll be a lot more consumption in that first year.

For the one year where they collected the taxes on the windfall income, the government would do really well.  The second year the government would lose 20% of its income tax revenues.  Why?  That's how much the 1% pay.  So either the government would have to increase tax rates or cut spending.  You might argue that the government could bank the excess from the first year.  OK, but then you can't also spend it on new social programs.

You'd also lose most estate tax revenues.  Fortunately that's not much money.

### Homelessness

After a year or so, there would be fewer jobs in this scenario because the consumption bump is a one-time thing.  Homelessness might well increase.  Remember that homelessness is as much of a mental health issue as a poverty issue.  Many probably wouldn't ever figure out how to collect their money.  And if they did collect their money, there's a strong chance that they'd drink it or otherwise waste it.

There would of course be some success stories.  But the mostly likely effect for most is that in five years they'd be in the same situation.

And don't forget, the rich also provide a significant portion of the charitable donations.  All that is gone.

### New businesses

In the first year a bunch of people would start new businesses.  But there would be no way to take them to the next level.  All the angel investors are in the 1%.

### No stars in movies

You wouldn't recognize anyone in a movie or TV show.  All the stars would be gone.  And that assumes that we could make movies and TV shows.  You know who's in the 1%?  Directors, producers, and actors.  There may be some unsuccessful directors and actors who could step up.  But for most, there are probably reasons why they have been unsuccessful.

And there go the major league sports teams.  And popular authors.  And rock stars.

### Loss of production

We'd also take some strong hits in areas like healthcare.  The 1% would take the doctors.  We'd be left with nurses and interns.  But the decreased life expectancy should help make up the shortfall in Medicare spending.

But that's not all of it.  We make fun of rich businesspeople, but they are doing things.  If they suddenly stop doing those things, it can make a difference.  We can promote a bunch of people, at least in those cases where the rich business person is not the sole owner as well.  But we should expect some loss of production from the loss of experience.

### Inflation

Loss of production combined with increased consumption causes inflation.

### Politics

I'm not convinced that money in politics is the be all and end all.  First, the largest recipient ever was Barack Obama.  Are you arguing that getting rid of the 1% would make the US more Republican?  Second, there have been several cases of the better funded candidate losing.

Another problem is that this would get rid of large individual donors and leave large corporate donors.  In some ways, that's less balanced, not more.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else would end up paying a whole lot more in taxes, as the top 1% pays like 80% of the income taxes.

It seems like there would be more hatred and fear, since the new 1% would now be the target when the vast majority of the "free money" that was just spread around will be spent extremely quickly and a large portion of the masses now want more.

That being said, if you are going to spend millions (billions?) on a bail out, it may be more efficient to direct it straight to the people rather than dumping it on corporations.